# Is it possible to compile NumPy into a single library?

Tags: python, numpy, compilation, cython

I have a use case where I want to deploy an application on end-user machines that don't necessarily have Python installed. Most of the application is written in Python, but the entry point is a legacy C++ application. This is why using tools like PyInstaller are not an option (although I'm certainly not an expert on this, so I could be wrong).

I am using Cython to embed the Python interpreter into the application. Everything is going more or less fine, but my Python code uses NumPy, which means there is still an external dependency. Ideally, I'd like to have a single binary that includes NumPy, as well as the Python interpreter, and my application code. Is it possible, using Cython or some other tool, to compile NumPy (or some portions of it that I am using) to a library that I can then link to my final executable binary? Or is it possible to somehow link to a wheel (or egg) containing the NumPy binary???

Comment: It is unclear to me, what you want to achieve. Numpy uses BLAS und LAPACK, do you want to put them also into this huge exe/so-file? What about builtin modules which are not part of libPython.so but its own so-files? You know you will have to hickjack the way modules are normally loaded? In my opinion it is far easier to use PyInstaller (why isn't this an option?) or come up with any other installation routine. This question is just too broad.

Comment: You'll probably need to statically compile numpy along with python: https://github.com/patmarion/NumpyBuiltinExample

Comment: There's also https://github.com/bfroehle/slither

Comment: ead: Ideally it would also bundle BLAS/LAPACK because I'd like to ensure it will run on systems that don't have any such libraries installed. Re: builtin modules, I guess I would include only those that are needed by the application. Re: PyInstaller, as I said, I'm not sure it isn't an option, but my understanding is it builds a single executable, whereas what I really want is a library (or set of libraries) that I can link to a C/C++ application. Not sure if that is possible with PyInstaller.

Comment: ngoldbaum: Those look really promising. Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking to use Nuitka (http://nuitka.net/) for this purpose. Anyone with experience with it? It looks even more promising than the others linked above.